# Cannot connect to Facebook, hosts file seemingly ignored

Tags: networking, factory-reset

I have a Motorola Atrix.

My country used to block Facebook, so I decided to add its ip to the `/etc/hosts` file about 3 months ago and it worked in the browser, but the Facebook app did not.

Now my country has unblocked Facebook so I would like to clear my hosts file and use Facebook as normal. However, my phone cannot connect to Facebook normally even after I performed a factory reset. Other devices still work without the modified hosts file.

Also, if I add some test lines to the hosts file such as:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test
```

then try to `ping test` in a terminal emulator it returns `unknown host`.

Is my hosts file being ignored? Did I miss something? I have OTA Root Keeper and it seemed to keep root after I did a factory reset. Did it keep something related to networks, too?

Comment: Could you include exactly what you enter to perform your ping test and into which program?  If the host file looks like what you provided and a ping of, say *facebook.com* results in *unknown host* that would imply that your DNS server is still trying to hide Facebook and that the host file is indeed being observed.  If your ping test was of *test* keep in mind that (at least what I've read is that) you may need to restart your phone after modifying the hosts file.  I must admit I haven't actually done this but I have read other reports where some programs actually cache DNS results.

Comment: I use Terminal emulator to do that (with root permission)

Comment: I already restart it

Comment: What did you use to edit the hosts file?

Comment: Before that I copy it to another folder, modify it then copy it back. When I remove host data, I delete it then create a new blank one :D

Comment: `I have OTA Root Keeper and it seemed to keep root after I did a factory reset` - Performing a factory reset will not unroot you because it will not touch the `/system` partition. I don't think it will modify `/etc` either, which could be why it did not reset your hosts file.

Comment: I meant what application on what device (phone/pc)           @eldarerathis yes you're correct /etc is actually /system/etc.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I type the following command on Terminal Emulator: echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts

Comment: Do you know if your friends can use the facebook app on their devices in your country? There's a small chance that the country unblocked the main facebook domain, for example, but forgot to unblock other domains used by the facebook app. Just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Yes, my friend can use FB for now. no bloking anymore. It's just my phone did not forget the host setting. I just want to clear it .....

Comment: It's just like the host file my phone used is not the host file it see in `/etc/hosts` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Applications menu in settings -- at least that what I think it's called on Gingerbread, on on ICS it's just Apps -- select the Facebook app and clear the cache as well as the data. Then go to the `/Android` folder on your SD card and delete anything starting with `com.facebook`.

Finally, reboot your phone. If your problem was related to the Facebook app it should now be fixed.

Comment: I've already do a factory reset. Did not work at all :(

Comment: I didn't even mention a factory reset. In particular, a factory reset doesn't affect the SD card.

Comment: Already try, caan not connect to fb services :(

Comment: The point is not only facebook app, but I've try fb in browser... Cannot connect either.
I just wanto get rid of the host file...

Answer (score 1):

Using a root explorer application, navigate to `/system/etc` and delete anything that is named `hosts` including any backups, then restart the device.

You may also need to clear the facebook app data as well.

Comment: Tried, not work. I have to unlock bootloader then reinstall OS :(